# function define in .h declared in .cu

Tags: c++, reference, cuda, undefined

I made a project split in three folders : src, include, obj
I am using CImg.h and cuda.h library. 
I declare `void convolve(cimg_library::CImg<float>&, cimg_library::CImg<float> const &);`in convolve.h
and define it in convolve.cu

my files :

main.cpp :

```
#include "CImg.h"
#include "../include/convolve.h" 
using namespace cimg_library;

int main(){
CImg<float> var1("/*path*/");
CImg<float> var2("/*path2*/");
convolve(var1,var2);
//some code
}
```

convolve.h :

```
  1 #ifndef CONVOLVE_H
  2 #define CONVOLVE_H
  //some define
  10 void convolve(cimg_library::CImg<float>&, cimg_library::CImg<float> const &);
  11 #endif //CONVOLVE_H
```

convolve.cu :

```
1 void convolve(CImg<float>& img, const CImg<float>& kernel){
//some code
24     kernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlocks>>>(/*some arg*/);
}
```

and my new makefile :

```
1 CC=nvcc
2 CX=g++
3 IDIR =../include
4 special_IDIR = /usr/local/cuda-9.0/include
5 LDIR = /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64
6 CFLAGS=-I$(special_IDIR) -L$(LDIR)
7 
8 LIBS = -lX11 -lpthread -lcudart
9 ODIR = ../obj
10 
11 
12 _DEPS = convolve.h kernel.cuh
13 DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))
14 
15 _OBJ = main.o convolve.o kernel.o
16 OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
17 
18 $(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
19         $(CX) -x c++ -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
20 
21 $(ODIR)/%.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
22         $(CC) -cu -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
23 
24 all: $(OBJ)
25         $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) 
26 
27 
28 .PHONY: clean
29 
30 clean:
31         rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

Here is my issue : it says the reference to `void convolve(cimg_library::CImg<float>&, cimg_library::CImg<float> const &)` is undefined.

I think this is because I never clearly say to the compiler that the definition of convolve is in convolve.cu. But I do not find how to make this link properly.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think you need to add `-c` on this line: `$(CX) -c -x c++ -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)`  Also, although it is not the issue you are reporting, for a function defined with reference parameters, it should not be necessary to add the ampersands on the arguments in the call to that function: `convolve(&var1,&var2);`  this should be sufficient: `convolve(var1,var2);`

Comment: Oh yes that's true for convolve(&var1,&var2); I had changed that but forgotten to change into my post.
About the -c on the line `$(CX) -c -x c++ -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)` if I add it, the compiler say there is no rule for ../obj/convolve.o

Comment: Yes, that is a different issue, due to junk in your `Makefile`.  See my answer for a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. please don't post code (or Makefile contents) with line numbers.  It just gets in the way, usually.
2. The compilation process here follows a compile...link process.  The first stage is the compile stage, and you should be using `-c` for both `g++` and `nvcc` during this stage (i.e. for both types of Makefile targets)
3. `nvcc` has no `-cu` option.  I think maybe you meant `-x cu`

I also removed the ampersands on the function call.

Here is a simplified example based on what you have shown, primarily removing the `CImg` stuff and some other unnecessary items:

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include "convolve.h"

int main(){

int var1 = 0;
int var2 = 1;
convolve(var1, var2);
}
$ cat convolve.h
void convolve(int &, int &);
$ cat convolve.cu
#include "convolve.h"

__global__ void kernel(){};

void convolve(int & i1, int & i2){

kernel<<<1,1>>>();
}
$ cat Makefile
CC=nvcc
CX=g++
IDIR = .
special_IDIR = /usr/local/cuda-9.1/include
LDIR = /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64
CFLAGS=-I$(special_IDIR) -L$(LDIR)
LIBS =
ODIR = .
_DEPS = convolve.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))
_OBJ = main.o convolve.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cu $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -x cu -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
        $(CX) -c -x c++ -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
all: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
$ make clean
rm -f ./*.o *~ core /*~
$ make
g++ -c -x c++ -o main.o main.cpp -I/usr/local/cuda-9.1/include -L/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64
nvcc -c -x cu -o convolve.o convolve.cu -I/usr/local/cuda-9.1/include -L/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64
nvcc -o all main.o convolve.o -I/usr/local/cuda-9.1/include -L/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64
$
```

change the instances of `cuda-9.1` to `cuda-9.0` in the above Makefile if you have CUDA 9.0 in your setup.  The linker libs (`-L`) are not really needed for the compile commands, however.  When linking with `nvcc` as we are doing here, it's also unnecessary to pass the `-I` and `-L` switches that refer to the CUDA includes and CUDA libraries that are part of the toolkit.  `nvcc` already knows how to find those.

There may be any number of additional recommendations or tweaks to the Makefile, for instance the `-x cu` and `-x c++` switches are probably unnecessary (at least they are unnecessary for my simplified example) but my objective here is not to create the perfect Makefile, but to give you a roadmap to get past the issue you are currently witnessing.